# How to fit a t-distribution with scale and location parameters in fitdistrplus

Tags: r, fitdistrplus

How can I use fitdistrplus to estimate the location a scale parameters of a t-distribution? I know that I need to provide initial values (in MASS it works very well) but in this package only the df is allowed. Do you have some solution?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The location and scale parameters in base R can be extended according to this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Location%E2%80%93scale_family) article.

```
library(fitdistrplus)
x<-rt(100,23)
dt_ls <- function(x, df=1, mu=0, sigma=1) 1/sigma * dt((x - mu)/sigma, df)
pt_ls <- function(q, df=1, mu=0, sigma=1)  pt((q - mu)/sigma, df)
qt_ls <- function(p, df=1, mu=0, sigma=1)  qt(p, df)*sigma + mu
rt_ls <- function(n, df=1, mu=0, sigma=1)  rt(n,df)*sigma + mu
fit.t<-fitdist(x, 't_ls', start =list(df=1,mu=mean(x),sigma=sd(x))) 
summary(fit.t)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `fitdist` function in the fitdistrplus package uses the distribution functions based on the distr parameter. So given this code:

```
data = 1.5*rt(10000,df=5) + 0.5
fit1 <- fitdist(data,"t",start=list(df=3))
```

`fitdist` is using the R functions `rt`,`dt`,`pt` and `qt`. But those functions do not support a location and scale parameter (and hence the above code will only optimise the df parameter and provide a very bad fit). So the solution is to use a version of the t-distribution that does provide the parameters you want. The metRology package provides such a version [metRology](https://artax.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/r-help/library/metRology/html/dt.scaled.html). The distribution in that package is called t.scaled, and the appropriate functions are defined (`rt.scaled`,`dt.scaled`,`pt.scaled` and `qt.scaled`).

Now you can fit for the three parameters df, mean and sd:

```
> library("metRology")
> fit2 <- fitdist(data,"t.scaled",
                  start=list(df=3,mean=mean(data),sd=sd(data)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The Student t distribution should take 2 parameters, the number of degree of freedom and the offset from zero number.  See if this works for you:

```
library(fitdistrplus)
#sample data
x<-rnorm(10, 2)

fitdist(x, "t", start= list(df=length(x), ncp=mean(x)))
```

The two reported values should be the estimated degrees of freedom and the offset values.